# After upgrading, effects are very slow

Tags: 11.04, gnome, compiz, ati, effects

...programs run normally, but the effects are very sluggish.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Well... you could start by adding some detail to your question :D!

Answer (score 3):

### Disable Detect Refresh Rate, and Sync To Vblank

- Install **CompizConfig
  SettingsManager** by running the
  following command in a terminal:

  `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
- Launch it by searching from the dash
  in Unity, or find it under
  **Preferences > CompizConfig Settings Manager** in Ubuntu Classic.
- Click on the **Composite** tab, and
  un-check Detect refresh rate.

[image]
[image]

- Click on the **OpenGL** tab, and
  un-check Sync to Vblank.

[image]
[image]

---

### Install drivers for your Graphics Processing Unit

- Open **Additional Drivers** by
  searching from the dash    in Unity,
  or find it under    **Administration >
  Additional Drivers** in Ubuntu Classic.
- Install/Activate any available
  drivers for your GPU.
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you're using your graphics card to its potential

you may need to install mesa-utils

do glxinfo | grep rendering

you should see Direct Rendering: Yes

In your cause hopefully it will say no which means that you need to install the proper drivers for your video card.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the newest Ati propriety drivers the problems *could* be the Tear Free Desktop setting.

Go to the Catalyst Control Center and find Tear Free under the Display Options and disable it.

This is what was causing sluggish effects on my machine, but because you didn't give us much detail on your problem, this answer is just a blind shot...

Comment: I did it, there is no change...